# Approximate gradient with a single function evaluation

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, optimization, gradient-descent

This question is about Lemma 1 of [Online convex optimization in the bandit setting: gradient descent without a gradient](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0408007). This lemma can be stated as:

> *Let $a\mathbb{B} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \ | \ \|x\|\leq a \}$ and $a\mathbb{S} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \ | \ \|x\|=a \}$. Then, for some constant $\delta>0$,
>   $$
> \mathbf{E}_{u\in 1\mathbb{S}}[f(x+\delta u)u] = \frac{\delta}{d} \nabla (\mathbf{E}_{v\in 1\mathbb{B}}[f(x+\delta v)]).
> $$*

First, for the $d=1$, I understand that we have
$$
\mathbf{E}_{u\in 1\mathbb{S}}[f(x+\delta u)u] = \frac{1}{2}f(x+\delta) - \frac{1}{2}f(x-\delta)
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{E}_{v\in 1\mathbb{B}}[f(x+\delta v)] = \int_{-1}^1 f(x+\delta v) \frac{1}{2} \ dv = \frac{1}{2\delta} \int_{-\delta}^\delta f(x+w) \ dw = \frac{1}{2\delta} F(x+\delta) - \frac{1}{2\delta} F(x-\delta),
$$
where $\frac{d}{dy} F(y) := f(y)$. However, in the paper they claim that $\frac{d}{dx} F(x+\delta) = f(x+\delta)$, which let us write
$$
\mathbf{E}_{u\in 1\mathbb{S}}[f(x+\delta u)u] = \frac{1}{2}f(x+\delta) - \frac{1}{2}f(x-\delta) = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2}F(x+\delta) - \frac{1}{2}F(x-\delta) \right) = \delta \mathbf{E}_{v\in 1\mathbb{B}}[f(x+\delta v)].
$$

- **The first part of the question is: how can we conclude that $\frac{d}{dy} F(y) =
     f(y)$ implies $\frac{d}{dx} F(x+\delta) = f(x+\delta)$? Is is because
  $\delta$ is a constant? Or am I missing something?**

For the general $d$-dimensional case, the authors state that 
$$
\mathbf{E}_{v\in 1\mathbb{B}}[f(x+\delta v)] = \frac{\int_{\delta \mathbb{B}} f(x+v) \ dv}{\text{vol}_d (\delta \mathbb{B})}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{E}_{u\in 1\mathbb{S}}[f(x+\delta u)u] = \frac{\int_{\delta \mathbb{S}} f(x+u) \frac{u}{\|u\|} \ du}{\text{vol}_{d-1} (\delta \mathbb{S})}. \tag{1}
$$
Then, from Stoke's theorem,
$$
\nabla \int_{\delta \mathbb{B}} f(x+v) \ dv = \int_{\delta \mathbb{S}} f(x+u) \frac{u}{\|u\|} \ du. \tag{2}
$$
Combining these equations, we get
$$
\text{vol}_d (\delta \mathbb{B}) \nabla \mathbf{E}_{v\in 1\mathbb{B}}[f(x+\delta v)] = \text{vol}_{d-1} (\delta \mathbb{S}) \mathbf{E}_{u\in 1\mathbb{S}}[f(x+\delta u)u].
$$
The lemma then follows from the fact that $\frac{\text{vol}_d (\delta \mathbb{B})}{\text{vol}_{d-1} (\delta \mathbb{S})} = \frac{\delta}{d}$.

- **The second part of the question is: How do you arrive at Equation (1)? I assume $\text{vol}_{d-1} (\delta \mathbb{S})$ refers to the surface area of the $(d-1)$-dimensional ball, but I don't see how that pops up there. Moreover, how do you arrive at Equation (2) from Stoke's theorem?**